# Inserting data into 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to ask how we can insert data in multiple tables in a database.
I have 2 tables named university and department.

```
university
uni_id |uni_name

department
dept_id|uni_id|dname
```

uni_id is a foreign key in department and uni_id is set to auto increment in university table...

```
insert into university (uni_name) values ("any uni");
insert into department ( uni_id,dname )  values ("same as in uni_id in university table","any")
```

I'm unable to insert uni_id in department table (foreign key). Same problem in university table.

Comment: You have tagged your question with both mysql and sql-server (Microsoft). What are you really using?

Comment: sorry ..i have tagged sql-server by mistake.. i am using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will work:

```
insert into university (uni_name) values ("any uni");
insert into department ( uni_id,dname )  values (LAST_INSERT_ID(),"any")
```

Comment: if its help you, then you should give up vote and accept this answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by insert select with inner join like this :

```
 insert into department ( uni_id,dname )  
 select u.uni_id , "any" 
 from university u 
 inner join department d
 on d.uni_id = u.uni_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into university (uni_name) values ("any uni");
```

While inserting into department table do

```
insert into department ( uni_id,dname ) 
 select u.uni_id , "any" 
 from university where uni_name = "any uni";
```